# Android - calling asynctask from asyntask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have to build some data from a json call and populate an object in Android mobile dev.

The json requires the read of the first url to get a list of data.  One of the fields is an url to an image which I need to make a second call to the web using asyncTask to retrieve as a blob and save in the object.

I have the code working to get the first url call using the asyncTask. But as I process each set of data I need to make the second asyncTask call to get the image blob.

Is this possible or maybe I am going about it wrong? Sorry no code snippets.

Comment: Why dont you do "The json requires the read of the first url to get a list of data. One of the fields is a url to an image which i need to make a second call to the web  to retrieve as a blob and save in the obj." in the doinbackground of a single asynctask. After parsing Json and getting url of image, do the http request to get the image

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to display those images or download those images received in first asyncTask. I would suggest you for both purposes to use a library like [picaso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [fresco](http://frescolib.org/).

Comment: No the the first asyncTask gets a list of fields, one being a url link to an image.  I need to make a second call using this url link to save the image as blob data.  this is then saved in a dbase for offline viewing.  The data and images are weather images and data.  Hence have to make async call to get array of data.  Then for each element of array make a second async call to get the image data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that tough as you are thinking.Follow the below example to parse image and data from json and display them:

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Create a separate package and copy the `ImageLoader.java` ,`MemoryCache.java` ,`FileCache.java` `Utils.java`

Then you can set your image within the adapter using the image url as:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader= new ImageLoader(context);
imageLoader.DisplayImage("the image url", imageview);
```

You can then reuse the **imageloader class** again and again throughout your project.

Apart from this you can also use third party apis to download images.

Some of them are [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Currently I am using Glide.It is very powerful and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Over thinking it. I can make 2 http request under same task. Problem solved.